# Displaying the records by Date in HTML Table

Tags: angular

In Angular 4 application

i'm having dashboard with three buttons such as 
1. Past Records,
2. Today Records
3. Upcoming Records

i need to display the records from the firebase based on the button click in html table
if i clicked the Today records the table need to come up with records that are matching the today date.
similarly for Past Records and Future Records is there any ng statements available to check for the date with table entries while looping through?

Comment: you can easily create a filter based on some condition. add code what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Given your date of creation is stored in `createdAt` and you use Firestore :

```
getRecords(moment: '-1' | '0' | '1') {
  const query: QueryFn = ref => {
    const ret = ref;
    if (+moment < 0) { 
      const date = new Date();
      date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      ret = ref.where('createdAt', '>=', date);
    }
    else if (+moment > 0) { 
      const date = new Date();
      date.setHours(23,59,59,999);
      ret = ref.where('createdAt', '<=', date);
    }
    else { 
      const end = new Date();
      end.setHours(23,59,59,999);
      const start = new Date();
      start.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      ret = ref.where('createdAt', '<=', end).where('createdAt', '>=', start);
    }
    return ret;
  };
  return this.db.collection<any>('records', query);
}
```